# How to transfer merge two AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two accounts.

Account A : This has some aws resources which should not ideally have any downtime. This is registered under aaa@gmail.com
Account B : This account does not have any aws resources, but it has some aws credits. This is registered under bbb@gmail.com

I have the access to both accounts/both emails. How I can merge those two accounts so that I can utilize aws credits.
Any method with no downtime is preferred. After the merge/migration, I am willing to keep any account as my primary account.

Thank you.

Comment: If your merge is purely to take advantage of the credits, you could try contacting AWS Customer Service to have the credits transferred.

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [AWS knowledge center article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/merge-aws-accounts/) your requirement doesn't seem to be supported:

> Issue
>
> I have resources on multiple AWS accounts, and I want to merge all the
>   resources together under one account. Is this possible?
>
> Resolution
>
> It's not possible to merge multiple AWS accounts together.

There is suggestion which might help you

> However, you can use AWS Organizations to manage the permissions for
>   multiple AWS accounts, and then combine the billing in one
>   consolidated bill.
>
> You can also transfer some AWS resources between AWS accounts. For
>   example, with Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2), you can share
>   custom AMIs between accounts, which allows you to transfer instances
>   between accounts. Because each AWS service is unique, the way to move
>   resources between accounts varies by service. For more details, see
>   AWS Documentation.